# PHP - Foreach , print the arrays next to each other

Tags: php

```
$aSpelers = array('Cilessen', 'Janmaat', 'de Vrij' , 'Vlaar', 'Blind', 'de Jong', 'Sneijder');

$aRugnummers = array(1, 7, 3, 2, 5,8, 10 );

$Posities = array('doel', 'verdediging', 'verdediging', 'verdediging', 'verdediging','middenveld','middenveld');
```

Foreach()

Comment: well.....i got stuck with the foreach loop. i dont know how it works with 3 arrays

Comment: you want to show like Cilessen 1 doel, Janmaat 7 verdediging?

Comment: Please, at least try to formulate a *real question*. Just dumping code and having half a question in the title is really just short of an insult. Note that you can edit your question to make it more comprehensible. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what do you want. I think you want like bellow code.

```
$arr[] = array('Cilessen', 'Janmaat', 'de Vrij' , 'Vlaar', 'Blind', 'de Jong', 'Sneijder');
    $arr[] = array(1, 7, 3, 2, 5,8, 10 );
    $arr[] = array('doel', 'verdediging', 'verdediging', 'verdediging', 'verdediging','middenveld','middenveld');
    foreach($arr as $array){        
        if(is_array($array)){
            foreach($array as $key=>$value){
                echo $value.'<br>';
            }
            echo '<br>';
        }       
    }
```